# Assigning row rank numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking, rank

I have a database. I want to update a column of it. The column should contain unique integer numbers in ascending order according to alphabetical order of another column.

Sorry not clear maybe, I want to have integer numbers like this:

```
1 ACC 501
2 BCC 501
3 GCC 601
4 FCC 601
```

Is there a reasonably simple way of setting this rank/order with mysql or sql query?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a ranking function which is not supported by MySQL at the moment. However, you can simulate them like so:

```
Set @rownum := 0;

Select rnk, SomeCode, SomeNum
From    (
        Select @rownum := @rownum + 1 As rnk, SomeCode, SomeNum
        From MyTable
        Order By SomeCode Asc
        ) As Z
```

Comment: Have to be careful -- the variable approach has only worked for InnoDB tables IME.  Had consistency issues when against MyISAM tables.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Granted. Course, there are other solutions such a different database product but I digress. :)

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas, that's exactly what I was looking for. But still there is one problem, this will rank the "result set" where as I want this ranking/order permanently in my database. If you know joomla then you might know that "categories" are ordered according to the "ordering" column,I just want to order it alphabetically. Let say, if I give order number one to ACC501, this category will be on number one and if I give it order no. 4 it will be on no. 4. I just want to assign them order numbers in a way that a should have order no.1 and b -2 and c-3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Create another table that has the same schema as your original table, plus the new column. The new column should be an autonumber. Do an INSERT...SELECT into that table. The new column will be filled out with the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Like what Alex said, you want to create a new table like

```
CREATE TABLE newTable(
#Table definition from current table,
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
);
```

And then insert with

```
INSERT INTO newTable
SELECT * FROM oldTable
ORDER BY orderColumn;
```

I think you can quickly do the create table with

```
CREATE TABLE newTable LIKE oldTable;
ALTER TABLE newTable ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```